# A question about Algebra

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation

4 years ago I have not been in sight for a math book. Today I had a dumb question.
I hope you can understand me.

$(\sin(x))^2$ is $\sin(x^2)$ or $\sin^2(x)$

I believe that to learn calculus, the first thing I have to do is accept that I have difficulties in basic areas such as trigonometry.

Comment: The second one.

Comment: The second one?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$(f(x))^2$ is often written as $f^2(x)$ and in general, $(f(x))^2\ne f(x^2)$

Example, $(\sin x)^2=\sin^2x, (\cosh x)^2=\cosh^2x, (\log x)^2=\log^2x$

Of course, in many functions like  Algebraic/Polynomial ones, $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ this notation does not make sense.

Comment: You answer is all. thanks

Comment: @Rakisbro, welcome anytime.

Comment: This notation isn't generally understood to have the same meaning unless the function is trigonometric.

Comment: @DanBrumleve, is that the reason for down-voting? It's too obvious that we can't use this notation for Algebraic/Polynomial/Exponential/Logarithmic Function unlike for Trigonometric/Hyperbolic.

Comment: Yes.  Why is it obvious that $\tan^2{x}$ should mean $(\tan{x})^2$ but $\log^2{x}$ should mean something else?  I explained my opinion in my own answer.

Comment: @DanBrumleve, so you admit, this notation is sometimes understood even when the function is not trigonometric? About my last comment, it should be "for Algebraic/Polynomial/Exponential Function unlike for Trigonometric/Hyperbolic/Logarithmic"?

Comment: For your first question: maybe sometimes, but not in general.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6387/discussion-between-dan-brumleve-and-lab-bhattacharjee)

Answer (score 2):

With trigonometric functions, such as $y= \tan(x)$, it is standard to write $$y^2=\tan^2(x)$$

Answer (score 2):

As Linear Man says, this is a common notation for trigonometric functions.  However, in a more general context, $f^2(x)$ may mean $f(f(x))$ rather than $(f(x))^2$ as lab bhattacharjee claims.  I think it is a poor notation for any other meaning even when limited to trigonometric functions and I prefer to write $(\sin{x})^2$ or $\sin{(x)}^2$ when I mean that, and I am quite comfortable with $\sin^2{(x)}$ or even $\sin^2{x}$ as a notation for $\sin{(\sin{(x)})}$ or with equivalent unambiguity $\sin{\sin{x}}$.